# Converting IF-else construct to SWITCH in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I understand that we can convert if-else construct to switch in java, using Quick Assist (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> ) in eclipse. However, I have a situation here, where I have to make workspace wide change. Is anyone aware how that will be done.

Also, any idea how the below construct can be converted using a tool?

```
if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '0') {
    getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Alright For Agent To Renew");
} else {
    if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '1') {
        getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Computer Renew");
    } else {
        if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '2') {
            getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Alright For Home Office To renew");
        } else {
            if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '3') {
                getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Already Renewed");
            } else {
                if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '4') {
                    getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Agent Issued First Policy, Computer To Renew");
                } else {
                    if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '7') {
                        getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Non-Renewal With A Notice");
                    } else {
                        if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '8') {
                            getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Non-Renewal Without A Notice");
                        } else {
                            if (getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).getBcRenewal0cd() == '9') {
                                getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("Cancelled Policy");
                            } else {
                                getBcListEntryArr38(wsCount).setBcRenewal0cdDesc("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: here you have an if - else, not an if - else if

Comment: agreed. Edited the question.

Comment: and now that you measure the time spent to find how to use the tool, don't you think that you could have wrote the code manually?

Comment: this is just an example. I have 1000+ constructs like this in the project which needs to be changed.

Comment: Why do you need to change them? Sure they are ugly, but switching to a switch will not really improve much. The example above for example I'd argue should be a map not a switch.
The reason I ask is that you are about to make a large change over a large chunk of code (automatically!), do you really have the testing resources to verify that change? 
I would recommend changing one construct at a time and doing it right. And only doing it when you are making a change to that chunk of code.

Comment: We are changing it to improve readability. We have many levels of nested iF-ELSE construct in the system. We want to start with few construct of code and if that works well, then ideally we would want to move for a system wide change. There is a exhaustive review and testing plan in place so that aspect will be taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

First convert this statement to `if-else if` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> then you will be able to convert the `if-else if` statement in a `switch`.

[image]

UPDATE:

Depending your Eclipse version, be aware there is a bug to "Convert `if-else`to `switch`" quick assist, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348179.

This is fixed: **Starting 4.3 Milestone 1 Eclipse will support converting if-else statements to switch statements.**

Comment: Does this answer the question ( I'm not sure) ? OP wants such conversion for many instances in the entire workspace not just a single class.

Answer (score -1):

public class question4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<6; x++) {
    if(x==1)
    System.out.println("x is one");
    else if(x==2)
    System.out.println("x is two");
    else if(x==3)
    System.out.println("x is three");
    else if(x==4)
    System.out.println("x is four");
    else
    System.out.println("x is not between 1 and 4");
    }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP wants to have it done automatically using an IDE..